# GeoJson Navigation map here

Tags: routes, navigation, maps, here-api

I am creating a navigation app in android studio Here Map. I have created a GeoJSON file with custom data  using ArcGis. I would like to know if there is a way to get navigation directions using this GeoJSON file and not from the Here Map driving routes?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!  Please review the submission guidelines in stackoverflow.com/help.

Comment: Are you basically asking how to do routing yourself and not using APIs?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the question is related to HERE Android Mobile SDK which provides navigation functions, it is necessary to create a route using the CoreRouter class. If there is a GeoJSON file then it would need to be parsed and converted into at least GeoCoordinates which can then be passed to the CoreRouter -> calculateRoute  function.

```
public void calculateRoute(java.util.List<GeoCoordinate> routePoints,
RouteOptions routeOptions,
Router.Listener<java.util.List<RouteResult>,RoutingError> listener)
Invokes an asynchronous route calculation. Upon completion of the request, the Listener will be invoked regardless if the request is completed successfully or not.
Parameters:
routePoints - The list of GeoCoordinate that is used for calculate a route. The list must have at least two items.
routeOptions - The RouteOptions is used for route calculation between points and for route recalculation during navigation mode.
listener - A Listener for the CoreRouter This method returns RoutingError.INVALID_PARAMETERS and a route will not be calculated if calculating a route with RouteOptions.TransportMode.PUBLIC_TRANSPORT This method returns RoutingError.INVALID_PARAMETERS and a route will not be calculated if calculating a route with RouteOptions.TransportMode.TRUCK and routePlan uses any Type other than FASTEST.
```

[Reference](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/content/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/routing/CoreRouter.html#calculateRoute-java.util.List-com.here.android.mpa.routing.RouteOptions-com.here.android.mpa.routing.Router.Listener-)

Comment: the route calculated from this method is going into every point entered in the routePoints list. How to calculate shortest/fastest route from these points.